# After freeze kivy , app run , but no window

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

My application run fine when executed from code , but when i freezes app with PyInstaller , they just don't open any window.

Here the part of the code https://gist.github.com/osnipezzini/a226b806a8ad5aa9000a30b723844db2

With debug=true , i can see this log , and python running main file , but no window start.

```
[7412] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[7412] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main\main.exe
[7412] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main
[7412] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[7412] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main\main.exe
[7412] LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
[7412] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main)
[7412] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[7412] LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main\python36.dll
[7412] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[7412] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[7412] LOADER: sys.prefix is C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main
[7412] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main\base_library.zip;C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main
[7412] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[7412] LOADER: Initializing python
[7412] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[7412] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main\base_library.zip;C:\Users\osnip\PycharmProjects\TelaBicos\dist\main
[7412] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[7412] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[7412] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[7412] LOADER: extracted struct
[7412] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[7412] LOADER: extracted pyimod01_os_path
[7412] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[7412] LOADER: extracted pyimod02_archive
[7412] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[7412] LOADER: extracted pyimod03_importers
[7412] LOADER: callfunction returned...
[7412] LOADER: Installing PYZ archive with Python modules.
[7412] LOADER: PYZ archive: PYZ-00.pyz
[7412] LOADER: Running pyiboot01_bootstrap.py
[7412] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgres.py
[7412] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py
[7412] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
[7412] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_kivy.py
[7412] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_gstreamer.py
[7412] LOADER: Running main.py
[7412] LOADER: OK.
[7412] LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

Comment: Are you using `--windowed` argument with pyinstaller?

Comment: Yes , have windowed option activated

Comment: i just used terminal + debug mode because errors

Comment: Check below answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code contain some `print()` functions and according to you when you tried to freez app with pyinstaller you passed `windowed` attribute which removes the console option.

**Main Problem**

Your Program tries to print something onto the console but there is no console available hence it shutdown.

Either remove those `print()` fucntions or remove `windowed` attribute during freezing
[image: main.py file contain print()]

Comment: Same problem , app run , but no window yet :(

Comment: Yes, it's running without problem from py file